# Scala - Convert Map to Json avoiding key/value keywords

Tags: json, scala, gson, filewriter, file-writing

Consider a simple map below:

```
val myTable:Map[String,Any] = Map(
"Table1" -> Array(
    Map("date" -> "2019"),
    Map("FilePath" -> "C:/Test")
))
```

I try to write it into a JSON file using the commands below:

```
import java.io.{File,FileWriter,Writer}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder

val gson: Gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().create()
val json =  gson.toJson(myTable)
val w: Writer = new FileWriter("C:/Test/output.json")
w.write(json)
w.close()
```

What I get in the json file is as following:

```
{
"key1": "Table1",
"value1": [
{
  "key1": "date",
  "value1": "2019"
},
{
  "key1": "FilePath",
  "value1": "C:/Test"
}
]
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to exclude "key1", "value1" words and instead print their actual values into the file (Please see the structure below):

```
{
"Table1": {
"date": "2019",
"FilePath": "C:/Test"
}
}
```

If it is relevant, I am using maven not sbt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

object JsonToString extends App {
  val myTable = Map(
    "Table1" -> Array(
      Map("date" -> "2019"),
      Map("FilePath" -> "C:/Test")
))

val jsonObject = Json.toJson(myTable)
println(jsonObject)
```

}

It should remove the key1, value1 words and instead use their actual value. Below are the list of maven dependency you need to add.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-json_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-M1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Madstuffs! I am new to scala and appreciate it if you can help me with the following issues that I face when trying to implement your solution: 1) For "import play.api.libs.json.Json", it says "cannot resolve symbol play"; why? 2) For "val jsonObject = Json.toJson(myTable)", it says "cannot resolve symbol Json" and asks me to add either "import org.apache.avro.data.Json" or "import org.json4s.jackson.{Json, Serialization}" 3) After adding it, now it doesn't like ".toJason"; why? 4) You used "println", if I need to write it to a file, should I simply use FileWriter as I mentioned above?

Comment: You need to add a maven dependency. I'll add it in the answer.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it! Was going to suggest using Play JSON. @Mahmoud, the println was just to give an example printing out the JSON. If you actually want to do something with the JSON (like use a FileWriter), yes you'd replace this line.

Comment: For example, if you wanted to make it pretty you'd do something like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/872ipw3QToKvQJIuwbAdeQ

Comment: Thanks James! With your additional suggestions it now works perfectly fine!